# Where does my weird way of saying 'no' comes from?

Tags: historical-linguistics, dialects, portuguese

At least in the region of Brazil where I come from (triângulo mineiro, Brazilian Texas I'd say.. we are considered the farmers of the Brazil also because of our accent ) people have a very weird way of saying 'no' to others. I discovered that it was weird after moving to the Netherlands where people are unaware of it.
It's like that: we suck the air in our mouths so that when we release our tongues from the roof of our mouths we make a noise. We do that twice and a bit fast. And this is an informal way of saying 'no' to others.
I'm very curious to know where this comes from. I don't even no the name of it and I think most people that use it are not aware of its weirdness.

Comment: I think this what in English is onomatopoeically written as *tut-tut* and called *tut-tutting*. Triplets - *tut-tut-tut* - are perhaps a little more common. It expresses disapproval, not denial or negation.

Comment: You might be right, the sound seems the same. If I were to record a scene showing disapproval, it would have someone pointing a finger and making the.. tut-tut-tut noise. So this sound is almost universally understood as disapproval even for my Dutch colleagues. But where I come from using it only twice really means negation. Both ways of tut-tutting probably have the same origin. I'm wondering where this started and how long ago it started meaning negation in Portuguese at least.

Comment: I've often seen it written, but I don't know what tut-tut sounds like.  Is it like tsk-tsk?  I think that is a rounded alveolar affricate click.  The Wikipedia entry for "dental click" claims that "tut" is just the British spelling of "tsk", and it gives a Portugese spelling "tsc".  (Nobody except me says it's rounded.)

Comment: "Click consonant" seems to be the right name and it has more info than "dental click" on wikipedia

Comment: Btw I'll search what a rounded alveolar affricate click is later when I get my headphones. I'll let you know if it's the same click.

Comment: "Rounded" means you purse your lips.  Just say it and watch to see if your lips purse.

Comment: My guess would be that this tsk-tsk sound derives from a no-no / não-não / non-non / n...-n... (depending of the language in which it originates, provided that the "no" word starts with "n"), under the influence of natural laziness.

Comment: @bli, so you're trying to say the [n] of "no", but through laziness you slip up and inadvertently make a dental click instead of the intended [n],  Hmmm.

Comment: I fail to see how an [n] can become a dental click out of sloppiness.

Comment: @Greg Lee, I don't know what you refer to by "slip up", and I don't think the that "tsk" sound qualifies as a *dental*. I just observe that when I try to say a double "no", without pronouncing the vocal sounds (the laziness causing the omission of at least the vocal sound between the two [n] sounds), the tip of my tongue makes a kind of "click" sound when it separates from the alveolar ridge.

Comment: @bli I agree that tsk is not dental, but rather alveolar.  I referred to it as "dental" because the reference in Wikipedia that I mentioned previously is in the entry for "dental click".  But that's not a very good reason.

Comment: @yurihbss A video would really be handy in this case.

Comment: Oh my state (Minas Gerais) is known for its peculiar laziness when talking... both in speed but also because we just don't bother saying the complete word when we are speaking...it's called caipira dialect. Best example is the phrase: Pode por pó? Pode por. Which means: Can I put powder? Yes, you can... In my state we'd say this phrase really like: Pó pô pó? Pó pô. So the only thing we change is the intonation of the O letter in this case... pretty lazy... The theory of the tut-tut arriving from slopiness when saying não-não(no no) isn't really farfetched...

Answer (score 2):

It seems obvious to me that this style of negation is related to one used by Arabs but also by many other people living around the Mediterranean. It's the same sound, not necessarily repeated, but accompanied by a characteristic head movement. You can see it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ipgtGuzDw8) as the first example.

Comment: Nice video! He explains really well that up north (he says America, but it's the same in the Netherlands where I'm from), clicking like that (but only once)  is a really rude way of showing disapproval. Which makes me wonder: where is the border between disapproval and negation?

Comment: I guess there is no strict border. Just like a word can mean one thing at one end of a dialect continuum and something quite different at the other end, with no clear demarcation anywhere between. As you go north, the sound probably becomes rarer slowly and gradually, and at the same time that it slowly becomes something rather exceptional, it slowly and gradually begins to express and invoke stronger feelings.

Comment: It might be related indeed. Although in Brazil we shake the head horizontally to both sides and not vertically and make the noise twice. Making the noise like in the video would mean dissatisfaction when used in a conversation. Making the noise like 5 five times in a row would mean disapproval but not very commonly used, more to mock someone about their 'wrongdoings'. That last gesture with the two fingers is also used in Brazil in the same context, also as mockery.